# storing ajax api calls in cache using HTML5

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile, html5-appcache

I have a mobile website, wherein i have a page which can be used for offline viewing, i am aware of the `manifest`, and added required resources in it.

Now i also want to cache data which is getting pulled from database, for which i have a web `API`, which pulls in content from database, and i am calling that web `API` in my web application using `jQuery`.

Below is the code i have tried:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#version 1

css/styles.css
js/script.js
js/libs/jquery-1.5.2.min.js
js/libs/underscore-min.js
```

Can anyone take me to the right path to do this.

Comment: Local Storage, perhaps?

Comment: Is it the safe way to store database content (e.g.: Users list) because with time it can get increase, i read that localstorage only supports 5MB of data, isn't it too less as the users base increases, is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Indexdb would suit your needs although general support on mobile is gradual but getting there-- http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb -

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach.

Suppose your api requests have URLs starting with `/api/*/*` you can set client side caching for this path to a very long duration. So when you are offline, your application will pick data from browser cache. For on-line mode, you will have to append cache busters to URLs. e.g. `/api/*/*?<timestamp>`. This should reduce the amount of logic that you will have to implement save to/read from localStorage and update localStorage values when data changes apart from saving to server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, Local Storage is only for small amounts of data.

You can try the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).
However, keep an eye on the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb).

### Edit

There are some shims that target older browsers, like [this one](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/). It defaults to WebSQL, who is pretty much [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=websql). It's nice to note that WebSQL is deprecated, though.

Comment: Browser support is very less especially for mobile browsers, it's too confined to specific versions, can we rather store the json request in a text file and stringify while reading back from it, is it possible in web applications.

Comment: It is possible, but you will need a connection to a server, and that will require an internet connection.

Comment: The file will not be on server, it will be on users mobile phone only, and the website will be accessed from the mobile platforms only.

Comment: If that is the case, wouldn't it pay off to go for a native app instead of a web site? Or, if a native app isn't worth the effort, what about [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [Meteor](https://meteor.com)? That way, you could on the first time download all the data you need and then you can queue requests to the server if no internet.